# Performance of EF Core Versus Web API for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, xamarin.forms

I am an ASP.Net Developer who uses Entity Framework Code First regularly. I literally began studying Xamarin Forms yesterday and my biggest question for any mobile platform has always centered around the easiest way to integrate with SQL Server. On initial research when I Googled using Xamarin Forms with SQL Server the consensus was binding through web services... which is fine but definitely a lot more work.

The thought occurred to me this morning about using EF with Xamarin Forms so I Googled it and apparently it is possible with EF Core. However before I go down that road I am hoping any of you could provide insights as to any significant performance differences with using EF Core to SQL Server remotely versus using Web API?

Obviously as far as app coding goes I would prefer EF Core but if there is a substantial difference in performance I would instead go the API route. Your experienced insights would be greatly appreciated and save a lot of time.

**UPDATE:**

Right after I posted this question I continued on in reading about EF Core within Xamarin Forms and apparently it uses SQLite. I had incorrectly assumed that since it was EF you could integrate with SQL Server. However after the two comments below it seems obvious that API is the way I should go even if it were possible. +1 for your comments and thank you for your help!

Comment: Who will be your end-user clients for your Mobile apps? Will it be public? Do you want to share your all of your database logic with your app for those people? 

If the app is just for your internal distribution, then i would think about managing database directly through the app other NOOO. I would never want to share anything regarding the Database from the app instead use the Web Api's to hide the details and only expose the business data with full secured way.

Comment: using EF Core would require your remote SQL Server to be exposed on the internet, which is rarely a good idea

Comment: @NirmalSubedi the app is for employees but they may be working remotely outside of our internal network at times.

Comment: Will you be going to implement Login in your app or Just let anyone to use the app and your database?

Comment: @NirmalSubedi Yes my initial thought was to use Domain Authentication for the App but after your comments and further research please see Update.

Comment: Seems like all you need in your app is - your users should be able to select the database, table and be able to execute the scripts. 
As you said before you want to avoid that extra work implementing the APIs and consuming them. But for your solution, I think you can make totally generic API and use them than creating api for each entities.

Comment: @NirmalSubedi Sounds really interesting, do you know of any posted examples of this type of approach?

Comment: Something like https://www.strathweb.com/2018/04/generic-and-dynamically-generated-controllers-in-asp-net-core-mvc/
Where you would create generic controller which will automatically expose the generic controller methods for all the models/entities. It will be very generic and will saves you a lot of time. Because you said you JUST need to expose the data so it should cover you most!